# Maven: Build only one module out of multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a multi-module Maven project wherein I just want to release an update module rather than the entire project. This is due to some specific requirements, wherein a release of entire project is uncalled for - only a subset of the library needs the fixes and thus the release.

However, when I run a `mvn release:prepare` I get the following error `Non-resolvable parent POM` - I have setup the parent POM relationship in the module project with `relativePath` tag but that does not seem to work.

Is it possible to release only a module rather than releasing the entire project.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Parent pom

```
<groupId>com.domain</groupId>
<artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>library1</module>
    <module>library2</module>
    <module>library3</module>
</modules>
```

The module POMs are as under:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.domain></groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>library1</artifactId>
```

Now I just want to release the new version of library1 and not others

Comment: can you provide fragments of your pom files which are describing relations and also structure of your project?

Comment: @user902383 added the POM fragments - thanks in advance

Comment: This confuses me a bit. Apparently you have three individually managed libraries with individual release and deployment trajectories, so I don't understand why they are then defined as three modules as if they must be packaged as one whole.

Comment: These are not 3 different libraries but modules of an uber library. With time other projects around 150+ depend on it. There is a critical fix that needs to be pushed and not all projects are ready to take it where they define vararg version. Thus the need for specific release

Answer (score 40):

```
mvn -pl .,library1 clean install
```

The "." will build your parent pom.xml and "library1" is the module name you gave it.

If you don't want to build the parent pom.xml, you can also do:

```
mvn -pl library1 clean install
```

or in your case, maybe:

```
mvn -pl library1 deploy
```

I used "deploy" because "release" is not a Maven build lifecycle phase.

Comment: what does -pl mean

Comment: -pl stands for "projects". It lets you specify the module that you want to build.

Answer (score 12):

Try running the maven commands from the parent project/directory with [the `-pl <project name>` switch](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#_specifying_a_subset_of_projects).

Comment: Doesn't work. `mvn clean package install` all targets work, but `release:prepare` fails.

Comment: Use artifactId instead of project name with pl switch

Answer (score 5):

the trick is both:

1. to repeat the -pl Param inside an additional -Darguments Param, to pass the -pl Param to the Child-Maven-Processes
2. the mysterious mavenExecutor, to be able to create the Child-Maven-Processes using the given -pl Param

This should work:

```
mvn -pl library1 -DmavenExecutorId=forked-path -Darguments="-pl library1"
```

Comment: for me the arguments parameter worked differently: `mvn -pl library1 -DmavenExecutorId=forked-path "-Darguments=-pl library1"`

Notice the different placing of the quotes.

Comment: Thank you!  Adding `-DmavenExecutorId=forked-path` was what I needed to avoid getting an error from the release:prepare child maven: `Failed to re-parse additional arguments for Maven invocation. Unrecognized option: -pl`

Answer (score 0):

I think maven is trying to tell you that the parent you defined is not released/stable. In your pom the parent version is "0.5.1-SNAPSHOT" which can not/should not work if you want to release a single library module as it would be pointing to something that is not uniquely defined. Is there a stable version you can point to instead? Otherwise maybe the -am switch works in combination with -pl?

### Edit

I tried this just now with maven 3.2 and it does ask me for what version the parent should be set/resolved to. It is as I stated previously you need stable version numbers for the release to work

```
mvn release:prepare -pl library1
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building library1 1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) @ library1 ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **\release.properties, **\pom.xml.next, **\pom.xml.releaseBackup,     **\pom.xml.backup, **\pom.xml.branch, **\pom.xml.tag [INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git status"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\temp\mavenTest\library1
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
There are still some remaining snapshot dependencies.
: Do you want to resolve them now? (yes/no) no: : yes
Dependency type to resolve,: specify the selection number ( 0:All 1:Project Dependencies 2:Plugins 3:Reports 4:Extensions ): (0/1/2/3) 1: : 1
Dependency 'testme:parent' is a snapshot (1.1-SNAPSHOT)
: Which release version should it be set to? 1.1: :
```